# How is LRU Caching faster than a hashmap?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, computer-science

I've not read up much about LRU Caching outside of what structures it's made of but I am still quite surprised at how much faster it is than a regular hashmap.

I did a test, a recursive combinatorics problem, using a regular hashmap to save the results of outcomes during recursion (dynamic programming), and did the same with the only difference being that an LRU cache implementation (size 1024) was used instead.

**The performance dropped from 1 second to 0.006 seconds!**

Now, this was very surprising, and I had no idea why this was the case. Hashmaps have an O(1) time complexity for most operations and an LRU cache requires *both* a hashmap *and* a doubly linked list.

context:

- I'm using c++ for this project. The hashmap in question is an unordered_map with a string as the key and an integer as the value. I have heard something about an unordered_map having a worst-case complexity of **N** or **N<sup>2</sup>**, but as far as I am aware, it usually performs all operations in **O(1)**.
- The LRU cache implementation was copypasted from stack overflow :D

## the code

#### with LRU caching

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

template <typename T,typename U>                                                   
std::pair<T,U> operator+(const std::pair<T,U> & l,const std::pair<T,U> & r) {   
    return {l.first+r.first,l.second+r.second};                                    
}
#pragma GCC optimize ("Ofast")
#pragma GCC target ("avx2")


// LRU Cache implementation
template <class KEY_T, class VAL_T> class LRUCache{
private:
        list< pair<KEY_T,VAL_T> > item_list;
        unordered_map<KEY_T, decltype(item_list.begin()) > item_map;
        size_t cache_size;
private:
        void clean(void){
                while(item_map.size()>cache_size){
                        auto last_it = item_list.end(); last_it --;
                        item_map.erase(last_it->first);
                        item_list.pop_back();
                }
        };
public:
        LRUCache(int cache_size_):cache_size(cache_size_){
                ;
        };

        void put(const KEY_T &key, const VAL_T &val){
                auto it = item_map.find(key);
                if(it != item_map.end()){
                        item_list.erase(it->second);
                        item_map.erase(it);
                }
                item_list.push_front(make_pair(key,val));
                item_map.insert(make_pair(key, item_list.begin()));
                clean();
        };
        bool exist(const KEY_T &key){
                return (item_map.count(key)>0);
        };
        VAL_T get(const KEY_T &key){
                assert(exist(key));
                auto it = item_map.find(key);
                item_list.splice(item_list.begin(), item_list, it->second);
                return it->second->second;
        };

};


// recursive solution to a combinatorics problem

// number of permutations of each parcel
int item_ways(int w, int n, int max_w){
    if (w == 0 and n == 0)
        return 1;
    if (w <= 0 or n <= 0)
        return 0;
    int ways = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= max_w; i++)
        ways += item_ways(w-i, n-1, i);
    return ways;
}   

// total combinations for answer
LRUCache<string,int> dp(1024);
//unordered_map<string,int> dp;
int parcel_ways(int p, int max_w, int n, int w){
    if (p == 0 and n == 0) 
        return 1;
    if (p <= 0 and n <= 0)
        return 0;

    string x; 
    x += char(p); 
    x += char(max_w);
    x += char(n);
    x += char(w);
    
    if(dp.exist(x)) // caching/dp skips recursion here
    {
        return dp.get(x);
    }

    int ways = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        ways += parcel_ways(p-1, max_w, n-i, w) * item_ways(w, i, max_w);
    }
    
    dp.put(x,ways); // cache here
    return ways;
}

// input any 4 numbers for problem
void solve()
{
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << parcel_ways(5,8,23,17);
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);
    cout << "Time taken by function: "
         << duration.count() << " microseconds" << endl;

}

int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

#### with an unordered_map (hashmap)

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

template <typename T,typename U>                                                   
std::pair<T,U> operator+(const std::pair<T,U> & l,const std::pair<T,U> & r) {   
    return {l.first+r.first,l.second+r.second};                                    
}
#pragma GCC optimize ("Ofast")
#pragma GCC target ("avx2")

// number of permutations of each parcel
int item_ways(int w, int n, int max_w){
    if (w == 0 and n == 0)
        return 1;
    if (w <= 0 or n <= 0)
        return 0;
    int ways = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= max_w; i++)
        ways += item_ways(w-i, n-1, i);
    return ways;
}   

// total combinations for answer
unordered_map<string,int> dp;
int parcel_ways(int p, int max_w, int n, int w){
    if (p == 0 and n == 0) 
        return 1;
    if (p <= 0 and n <= 0)
        return 0;

    string x; 
    x += char(p); 
    x += char(max_w);
    x += char(n);
    x += char(w);
    
    if(dp[x]) // caching/dp skips recursion here
    {
        return dp[x];
    }

    int ways = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        ways += parcel_ways(p-1, max_w, n-i, w) * item_ways(w, i, max_w);
    }
    
    dp[x] = ways; // cache here
    return ways;
}

void solve()
{
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << parcel_ways(5,8,23,17);
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);
    cout << "Time taken by function: "
         << duration.count() << " microseconds" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Edit] your question with [mcve] implementations of both versions.  Without code, we can only guess what's happening.

Comment: FWIW `unordered_map<T>` is just bad in terms of performance.  Because of requirements imposed by the standard it basically has to be implemented as a `std::vector<std::list<T>>`.  This guarantees at least one cache miss on every access and most likely more.  That means you're running at best at RAM speed.

Comment: when you measure for a fixed size then asymptotic complexity is rather irrelevant. Also compiler optimizations matter (what flags did you use to compile?). And of course without the code nobody will be able to tell why you observed that difference

Comment: Sorry everyone about not having any code, I've updated the post

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number my compiler flags were `-Wall -Wextra -std=c++17`, alongside the #pragmas in the code. I use gcc to compile.

Comment: the default setting is no optimizations. Measuring runtime without optimizations is not that useful. Try `-O3` for example

Comment: @ron0studios `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- Ugh.  `#define mp make_pair #define pb push_back #define ll long long` -- More Ugh. Are you using an "online competitive coding" website to write your examples?  There is also no input data.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yup this is competitive programming. I had to modify my usual template so the code wouldn't be atrocious, but it is still pretty bad XD. Here is some example input: `5 8 23 17`

Comment: well ok there  `#pragma GCC optimize ("Ofast")` in the code. It is hidden between terrible macros. I don't think you are even using them in the code, nevertheless  `#define mp make_pair` is bad. Even if you are not using them in the code, seeing the macros one has to be paranoic and be super careful, because anything written in the code could actually be something else. It requires the reader to keep unecessary stuff in mind to be able to read your code, just because you wanted to save some keystrokes

Comment: If that's the input data, the code should be `cout << parcel_ways(5,8,23,17);`, and remove the `cin` statements.

Comment: how did you measure the time?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I used std::chrono's high resolution clock around the `parcel_ways` function.

Comment: @ron0studios *I used std::chrono's high resolution clock* -- That should have been part of the posted code.

Comment: you should use `steady_clock` rather than `high_resolution_clock` for duration measurements

Comment: I added a high resolution clock and removed `cin` inputs.

Comment: apologies @463035818_is_not_a_number I only just read your comment on the high resolution clock. How big of a difference will this make?

Comment: `cout << parcel_ways(5,8,23,17);` -- You are timing the `cout` call, along with `parcel_ways`.  You should just time the `parcel_ways` function.

Comment: How big does the unordered_map get with or without the LRU logic?  My suspicion is that with the LRU logic keeping the size of the unordered_map bounded, your working set fits into the CPU's cache, but without that, the unordered_map gets very large and you see more cache-misses.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I think I see what you're getting at. This recursive function runs into the tens of millions, so I'm assuming the size of the maps must be big as well. May you please elaborate on why a bigger map size leads to a slower program? Thank you!

Comment: @ron0studios more data = more RAM used, which means (other things being equal) that the chances of any particular memory-access already being located in the CPU's cache become lower, which means that a larger percentage of memory accesses will have to wait for the data to be delivered from general RAM.  In the ideal case, all of the program's data would fit into cache and the CPU would never need to wait for RAM at all; that would allow the program to run at full CPU speed.  In the worst-case, there's so much data that you have to page data in and out from disk, and then it's glacially slow.

Comment: @ron0studios -- `if (dp[x])` Hopefully you are aware that this will *always* insert a new entry into the map if `x` doesn't exist as a key.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Oh my... I am really something else. I reran the code with the `contains` method instead and it works. Is there any alternative that works below c++20 though? because not many programming sites support it yet.

Comment: Im not sure whether I should answer my own question because other people have given very valid answers to the question as well, which may have contributed well for even larger test cases than my own, so I'll wait if they provide their own solutions before correcting my blunder. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @ron0studios -- Try [count](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/count).  If it returns 1, then the item exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of things that aren't optimal in your implementation, but the only thing I see that can make the magnitude of difference you are seeing is this:

```
if(dp[x]) // caching/dp skips recursion here
{
    return dp[x];
}
```

This will not return if `dp[x]==0`, so you will recalculate any 0 result.

The version with the LRU cache uses `exists`, which will do an early return in this case.

This can be done by using `dp.contains(x)` *(or `dp.count(x)` if you do not have c++20)*

Answer (score 1):

To implement LRU cache you need to make those operations efficiently

- Store entry by name
- Check if there is an entry stored for a given name
- Retrieving an entry by name
- Getting the number of elements stored
- Getting the oldest entry and evict it from the cache

If you want to implement LRU cache with only one data structure, the balanced tree would be the best choice because each operation takes `O(log(N))`. Or if you are sure that you have enough cache space and you do not need to purge any element you could use `hash table`.

But hash tables are terrible when it comes to maintaining an ordering of things that is why we need to use the doubly linked list.

In LRU cache implementation, to avoid duplication, linked lists stores the actual values and hash table stores the memory addresses of the nodes in linked list.

> Hashmaps have an O(1) time complexity for most operations

this statement is not correct. Storing and retrieving takes `O(1)` but removing the oldest entry takes `O(N)`  in hashmaps. when access an element that is stored on the cache, we need to move this existing element to the front of the list, and we can only do that efficiently in the doubly linked list rather than hash map. Since we stored pointers of linked list in hash map, we retrieve the element from hash map in O(1) time and delete it in o(1) by setting `retrieved_node.prev==Null` and `retrieved_node.prev==null`. but before you need to keep the references of `prev` and `next` to keep the connection of the linked list